# How to import from another folder (python)

Tags: python, import, directory

I am running from folder A (the name doesn't matter), and in this folder there is another folder called bin.

In bin I have the .py file "functions", how do I import it if I'm in folder A.

Reminder: main.py -> location: A

Reminder: functions.py -> location: A/bin

Thanks.

Comment: `from bin.functions import function1, function2` To be able to do this, make sure `bin/` has an `__init__.py`

Comment: yeah.. an empty file called `__init__.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an empty file `bin/__init__.py`. This will tell python that `bin` is a "package" and should look for modules there.

```
from bin import functions
```

If you want to do something like `from bin.functions import *` you can add which functions you want to load defining them in `__init__.py` (more [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package))

```
# __init__.py
__all__ = ["fun1", "fun2"]
# doing import * will load those 2
```

You can find more info [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: Another little question, if I want all of the functions to be imported (like: from hi import *) ?